# Hiding and Showing :before thru Jquery or better solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Ok, this is driving me crazy. We installed a WP plugin to create a "Mega Menu". Now the hover bottom arrow on each menu is being affected on the menus that have the this mega menu applied to ("Connect" and "Resources"). Originally, it was placed on the middle of its menus, but since the Mega Menus uses full width, the position gets screw up. So, I hidden the original "arrows" and created another one using a:before to the two mega menu links ("Connect" and "Resources"). Here is the link for the dev environment:

(link) (main menu)

My question: Is it possible to hide/show or border-bottom color change using pseudos (:before)? I could change the color every time the sub-menu is being displayed.

I would appreciate any help or suggestion of another solution if the one I am trying is not possible.

Also, let me know if you want me to revert back to the initial issue in case you think you can figure it out a better idea with out mine.

Thank you!

Comment: Hide mega menu arrow from css.

Comment: Ok. How do I have them display them dynamically every time the sub-menus are displayed?

Comment: Look at my answer. Find the css that controls the mega menu. First part is from your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not tested but something like this.

```
a:first-child:before {
    left: 50%;
    top: 9.5px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    content: " ";
    pointer-events: none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: auto;
    opacity: 0; /* here */
}

a:hover:first-child:before { /*hover*/
    opacity: 1;
}

li.megamenu:hover > a:first-child:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, the arrow would stay there only when the link is being hover, and not when the whole menu is being displayed. Makes sense? I just added to my css. Take a look.

Comment: Display default must be something else. Try with opacity. I am editing answer.

Comment: Yeah, but I would still have to have the opacity/color changed dinamically every time the sub menu is being displayed. Because on hover, would be only show the the menu title is being hover.

Comment: I just updated the css. But still not ideal. Do you understand what is the issue now? Thank for your help by the way

Comment: I saw it. I will find the correct place for this code. 
li:hover a

Comment: Add try the latest part

Comment: BTW they will delete this question because of the type of asking.

Comment: It works! Awesome! Thank you @emrah ! I really appreciated. Why would they deleted? Did I not asked the right question?

Comment: They will delete because it is too specific. They think it should help somebody else who come from google search.